# Unable to insert into 2d list in python

Tags: python, list, insert

I am trying to insert an element into the first column of each row in a table of data read from a text file.

```
grades = [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
student = ["Alice Arnold", "Cory Brown", "Sean Douglas", "Pete Douglas", "Mary Fleming", "Joel Jacob",
               "Jeramy Ghouse", "Hansie Holder", "Loyola Ingenious", "Gary Jackson", "Russell Jacobson",
               "Dustan Kellart", "Carl Melone" , "Samuel Peterson", "Alec Stewart"]
code = ""
s=0
for i in file:
    pos = 9
   
    code = file.read(pos)
    info = code.split("\n")
    indexRow = info.pop()
    row = int(indexRow[0:2])   #slice the first 2 digits for row index
    col = int(indexRow[2:4])   #slice the other 2 digits for the column index 
    gr = float(indexRow[5:9])   #slice the grade
    grades[row][col] = gr
    grades[row][0] = student[s]
    s+=1
```

The text file has two columns, one is a four digit code that must be broken down into proper indices for the position in the 2d list.  The other is a grade.  Each row is a student's grades, whose name I want to  insert at the beginning of the list at column 0 of each row.

I thought `grades[row][0] = student[s]` was the legal way to insert an item into a list, but I keep getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range" for this line.  Anything is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add sample text columns that gives you the trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use for loop using index rather then comprehension

```
for i in range(len(inputList()):
```